# pygame.draw.rect() not drwaing another rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, draw, rectangles

I am making a simple graphical game in pygame. I wanted to draw 2 rectangles but it only draws one not the other.

I made a class of drawing different figures. To fix that issue I removed the class and made a plain function. Id didn't work too. Then I just put the code of function statements in the program.

The final code I get is this

```py
import pygame

black = (0,0,0)
yellow = (200,200,0)

def drawShopButton():
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (690,435,110,65))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, yellow, (0,500,110,65))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
gameDisplay.fill((40, 120, 0))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (690,435,110,65))
pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(40)

pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, yellow, (0,500,110,65))
pygame.display.update()
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: in pygame you have to redraw everything. otherwise the screen gets overwritten. Also, you have to refill the screen each iteration before drawing the rest, i.e. gameDisplay.fill(...), and after that your pygame.draw functions, and after that pygame.update()

Comment: (0,500,110,65) is beyond your (800, 500) scope
Replace with say, `pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, yellow, (0,0,110,65))` and your code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left top corner of the game board is (0,0) and the bottom right corner is (800,500).
So, `pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, yellow, (0,500,110,65))` is trying to draw a rectangle that is starting at the right top of the board and is (110, 65) wide and tall.
Your code is drawing two rectangles alright, but beyond the visibility scope.